# Fancybox 2 loads the last item of the gallery when I'm using trigger('click')

Tags: php, fancybox

I realized that when I was using

```
$(.fancybox).fancybox().trigger('click')
```

to launch fb gallery during the window loading. My fb gallery loaded the last item of the gallery. Have no idea.

The thumbs' order is correct.

FB version 2

```
<?php foreach(***)?>  
  <a class="fancybox" href="*big image*"> 
    <img src="*thumb*" /> 
  </a>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Help, please, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote like this:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox();
$('.fancybox:first').trigger('click');
```

and it works. Now it loads the first item.

Comment: That looks pretty much like a good workaround. You may have done $('.fancybox').fancybox({'index': 0}).trigger('click'); with the same effect ... but you still won't know why it was loading the last. If you share a link with issue, I could tell you what to change.

Comment: http://www.haozhenyu.be/test/fancyapps/demo1/   (with 'index':0) doesn't work    http://www.haozhenyu.be/test/fancyapps/demo2/  (with ('.fancybox:first').trigger('click') ) it works

Comment: Well, I am sure you have the issue because you are using the same ID in more than one element within the same page so fancybox cannot validate the index and gets the last set. Check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#support FAQ's No.6 .... and additionally you should also set a proper DOCTYPE

Comment: thanks, this worked for me.  its important to call them separately. combining the fancybox bind call and the click causes it to load the first item, and no other items.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your class "fancybox" has or inherited a "`position:absolute`" within your CSS, so that makes the last image to be on top of the stack, hence it's displayed first.

Comment: I checked all css file, it changes nothing, always loading last item. so sad.. -_-